# Re-installing jenkins in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, continuous-integration, reinstall, jenkins-php

Well, I forgot my password for Jenkins and I tried(for one full day) with all usual passwords, failed in all attempts. Hence, I wanted to reinstall jenkins from scratch, luckily I was just setting up and I had no jobs configured yet.

So I removed (rm -Rf) of jenkins folder from tomcat webapps directory, and restarted tomcat. To my surprise Jenkins asks for login again.

What is the proper way to remove and reinstall jenkins? I have jenkins.war and I installed it by just copying it over to tomcat webapps.

Well either - I want to reset my password because I am the only admin or I want to reinstall jenkins from scratch. I have sudo access to the machine, could someone point me on how I can do this?

Jenkins version : 1.530

Comment: I am sorry, but I did do enough research before posting the question here...

Answer (score 0):

Well just nailed down the answer.

If `JENKINS_HOME` or `CATALINA_OPTS` is not specified, the config.xml was found in

```
/root/.jenkins/config.xml
/root/.jenkins/{{jenkins-userid}}/config.xml
```

So once I deleted the /root/.jenkins folder it was all fine.